# Convert Base-64 pfx to Usable pkcs#12

Tags: azure, powershell, openssl, ssl-certificate

I've exported a base 64-encoded certificate from an API and now need to convert it to a pkcs12 format to be uploaded to Azure. The below PowerShell script does this job perfectly, but I'm having trouble converting this to OpenSSL.

```
$base64value = Get-Content -Path $base64FilePath
$byteArray = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($base64value)
$cert = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]::new($byteArray, $certPw, [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]::Exportable)
# Export the certificate as a PFX file
$bytesPfx = $cert.Export([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ContentType]::Pfx, $certPw)
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($pkcs12FilePath, $bytesPfx)
```

I've tried the following 2 OpenSSL commands...

```
openssl base64 -d -a -in [base64.pfx] -out [converted.pfx]
```

```
openssl enc -base64 -d -in [base64.pfx] -out [converted.pfx]
```

...but these both return the same error when I attempt to use the certificate:

> 34359836736:error:0D07207B:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_get_object:header too long:crypto/asn1/asn1_lib.c:101:
> error in pkcs12

Any help with this conversion would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `-A` **(uppercase)** argument instead of `-a`.

According to [OpenSSL's documentation](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Command_Line_Utilities#Base64_Encoding_Strings), their base64 decoder is limited to 76 characters by default. So the expected output for the pkcs12 binary file is actually truncated to that limit. This is why you were getting the `header too long` error, due to the corrupted file generation.

The documentation suggests that you can use the `-A` option to overcome this limitation.

The final command would be:

```
openssl base64 -d -A -in certificate.b64 -out certificate.pfx
```

Bonus, if you want to convert it further into a PEM file:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in certificate.pfx -out certificate.pem -nodes
```

You can also include a `-clcerts` option if you only need the client certificates.

Answer (score -1):

You could try the below

Convert the pfx from the base64 openssl Binary format

```
openssl enc -base64 -d -in base64.pfx -out converted.pfx
```

Then convert it to pkcs12 :

```
openssl pkcs12 -in converted.pfx -out bundle.pem -clcerts -nodes
```